# Why is kubectl describe secret not working?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I created a secret in kubernetes using the command below -

```
kubectl create secret generic -n mynamespace test --from-file=a.txt
```

Now I try to view it using below commands but am unsuccessful -

```
kubectl describe secrets/test
kubectl get secret test -o json
```

This is the error I get in either case -

```
Error from server (NotFound): secrets "test" not found
```

What can be the cause? I am using GCP for the kubernetes setup. Can the trial version of GCP be the cause for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to access the secret in the namespace where it was created in:

```
kubectl -n mynamespace describe secrets/test
kubectl -n mynamespace get secret test -o json
```

Comment: Thanks @Cloudomation. I had almost figured that out.

Answer (score 2):

You create your secret on a specific namespace and not the default one and when you use `kubectl describe` it will be bind to the default one.

Good thinks to know when you use a specific namespace for your secret is that they can only be referenced by pods in that same namespace.